# Get a reliable mapping of users-to-computers in Active Directory environment

Tags: active-directory, users

Need to assign users to their workstations for purpose of assigning computer access for Remote Web Workplace in Small Business Server 2011.  To do this, I need a reliable list of users' workstations.  This would also be handy for discovery in new environments, so something automated or semi-automated would be preferred.

Couple of thoughts on how to achieve this:

- check/parse the security audit logs on the domain controller to match logon name to machine name in the logon events.
- write a logon script that echos logon name and hostname to a file on a network share.
- browse C$\Documents and Settings\ or c$\Users looking for most recently modified NTUser.dat
- Look in HK_USERS for SIDs and (possibly) find last logon time.
- Walk around and check each workstation name (boo! walking!)

Thinking the logon script might be the most hands-free and conclusive (will also show if users are on multiple machines and if so, would want to consider adding both machines to their profile).

Anything better?

NOTE: I should say that when setting up a new SBS server and using the http://connect method of joining to the domain, it will add the computer to the user's Remote Access tab > computer list.  However, we're often doing migrations from existing DCs or SBS servers and this mapping is not always present or accurate.

Comment: I use the login script method as well. Simple and to the point, you can throw a %date% %time% in there too and you can even tell if they're late for work. @Graeme Donaldson has a good additional answer I tried at one of my clients here http://serverfault.com/questions/44862/best-way-to-find-the-computer-a-user-last-logged-on-from/45078#45078

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The login-script method is the least-effort method of getting what you're looking for.

I've done the first method, which involved a fair amount of scripting in PowerShell, and requires regular exports of the domain controller's security event-log. The advantage to that method is that it'll get everyone on everything which may not be the case for the login-script method; important when I had close to 3000 active computer-objects out there.

For SBS where you're going to be working with an order of magnitude (or two) fewer machines, the login-script method is probably your best bet. You may get one or two special snowflakes, but those should be easy to work around.